# Pandas to filter values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

with 114 rows. The values of first 6 rows of `CPULabel` will repeat 19 times.
I tried to use the command below to filter the data which contains string `'Fast'` or `'Slow'`:

```
df[(df['CPULabel']=='BP100_Fast') | (df['CPULabel']=='100LoBW_Fast') | (df['CPULabel']=='100HiBW_Fast')]
df[(df['CPULabel']=='BP100_Slow') | (df['CPULabel']=='100LoBW_Slow') | (df['CPULabel']=='100HiBW_Slow')]
```

But sometimes different people will name it differently, the only thing in common is string `'Fast'` or `'Slow'`. I tried regular express before, It did not work.
Is there anyway to filter or choose certain values in on column?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `str.contains` with regex `(?i)fast|(?i)slow`, this will pick up strings containing either `fast` or `slow` with the case ignored:

```
df[df['CPULabel'].str.contains("(?i)fast|(?i)slow")]
```

---

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CPULabel": ["BP100_Fast", "BP100_Slow", "BP100"]})

df
#     CPULabel
#0  BP100_Fast
#1  BP100_Slow
#2       BP100

df[df['CPULabel'].str.contains("(?i)fast|(?i)slow")]

#     CPULabel
#0  BP100_Fast
#1  BP100_Slow
```

Comment: It is exactly what I want. Thank you very much.